# How to use awk to print everyline after the 1st line, if you keep executing the script?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a text file generated by `calcurse` to list my calendar events. The content of the file is something like this:

```
01/23/23:
 * Homework                                                                              
 * Sports
```

Time is not important, I only want to see the events. The point is I want this to be displayed in my window manager (i3wm).  I am thinking off creating a button that executes a script on click (possible with `polybar`). This script would display the 2nd line of the text file; and upon clicking, the script would display the 3rd line and so on... Reason for displaying individual line is because the i3bar's width is small so can only display 1 line (1 event).

I am thinking of using `awk`, and I could test the following:

```
head -1 myfile | awk '{print $1}' gives 01/23/23:
head -2 myfile | awk '{print $2}' gives Homework
```

But

```
 head -3 myfile | awk '{print $3}'
```

does not produce Sports.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: If `print $2` gave you `Homework` then why did you not use `$2` for `Sports` line as well?

Comment: Reading your input file from the top is rather unfortunate from an efficiency perspective here. If you were dealing with software that gave you access to `seek()` and `tell()` -- which pretty much any non-shell language's file I/O will support -- you could at least store byte offsets to be able to jump direct to the right part of the file instead of needing to count lines starting from the very top.

Comment: _Sports_ is in the second field of the line. `$3` is the third field, which does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

No need for `head`:

```
awk -v n=3 'NR==n { sub(/^ \* /,""); print; exit }' myfile
```

You weren't seeing `Sports` output from your code because `print $3` was trying to print the 3rd field of a line that only has 2 fields, `*` and `Sports`.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an aside, but - `head` is looking at lines. `awk` (in your examples) is looking at the fields of every line `head` passes.

Using

```
01/23/23:
 * Homework                                                                              
 * Sports
```

Then

```
head -1 myfile | awk '{print $1}' # gives 01/23/23:
```

This returns the date not because `$1` refers to the first *line*, but to the first *field* of the **only** line it received.

```
head -2 myfile | awk '{print $2}' # gives Homework
```

this, again, refers to *fields*.
It reads the first line, in which the date is `$1`, but there is no `$2`, though it should print an empty line for it. The `head -2` prevents it from processing line 3, or it would print `Sports` also. In both of these `$1` was the asterisk.

```
head -3 myfile | awk '{print $3}'
```

None of these lines *has* a third field.

To do what you are suggesting as I understand it, you need a way to track which line you want each time you call it.

If you are able to make subsequent calls passing in the lines to `head`, then Ed's `awk` solution is much better.